# OS X Sierra + XAMPP 7.1.9-0 + Extension mongodb.so is not starting

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, xampp, homebrew

I am working with the latest OS X Sierra 10.12.6, XAMPP 7.1.9 with PHP 7.1 and I install the latest Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 7598; last commit 2017-10-18) to achieve this goal: Use the latest mongodb-extension (that is replacing the old mongo-extension).

After a clean install of mongodb like this:

```
 brew tap homebrew/php
 brew install php71-mongodb
```

I found the mongodb extension in:

```
 /usr/local/opt/php71-mongodb/mongodb.so
```

I add this to the php.ini file of my XAMPP-installation:
*/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc*

```
extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-mongodb/mongodb.so"
```

After that I am going to restart XAMPP respectively the Apache2 service:
 */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ctlscript.sh* restart apache

The only response I will receive is anything but an error:

> AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next
>   release /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40
>   Syntax OK /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh :
>   apache not running AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be
>   removed in the next release
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40 Syntax
>   OK /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd
>   started

**The strange thing begins here:**

When I use the XAMPP user interface to restart the service, Apache2 is not working anymore.

*Even* restarting the service on CLI will fix this.

*Even* after removing the reference to the mongodb.so from the php.ini will fix this.

The problem is: I don't receive any kind of error. Not in */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/php_error.log* nor in */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error.log*.

Answer (score 0):

**see update below**

I found a way to restart the Apache2 service with a working mongodb-extension in this thread:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/247

Restarting the service on CLI with this command helped me:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log
```

Thats all.

But I still *do not* understand how all of this is connected. When using the XAMPP UI again to restart, it's not working, again. But the UI did work in the beginning. So, somehow the installation of the mongodb-files (or maybe homebrew) damaged something somewhere in the XAMPP-installation.

## Update, next day

I installed a fresh XAMPP, from the scratched 
It took a while to find out, what the XAMPP UI does to start the apache, it's a chain of commands:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ctlscript.sh start apache
-> 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh start
->
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp startapache 
-> 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl -k start -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
->
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -k start -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
```

After that I added the famous mongodb.so-line to the php.ini file.

From now on, I was not able to use the UI to start Apache again. So I took the last command from the chain above and executed it, with this result:

> (13)Permission denied: AH00086: httpd: could not open error log file
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log. AH00548:
>   NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40
>   (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   [::]:80 (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs

**Finding #1:** Just adding the extension to the php.ini kind of removes the write flag from the error.log

So, this is easy to fix with

```
sudo chmod a+w /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log.
```

Now, for the first time in the history of this issue, I got a real error message from the error.log, that is telling something to me:

> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   [::]:80 
>   (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs

Finding #2: Starting the Apache as sudo from the command line will fix it

## Remaining mysterys

It is still not clear to my, what happens after adding the extension to the php.ini. Even removing it will not fix the problem.